# Soundcloud windget setVolume not working at all

Tags: javascript, widget, soundcloud

Soundcloud widget is a great thing but volume control is completely broken. JS api calls to setVolume just ignored by player, tested in latest Chrome and Firefox.

Broken volume control can be easily seen at official playground page - https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html

Some time ago there was workaround - [SoundCloud Widget API setVolume Method broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329013/soundcloud-widget-api-setvolume-method-broken) - but now even this hack does not work. Please fix widget API. without volume control it is almost unusable ( Btw, workaround is not ok anyway, since first second of loaded sound still playing at full volume, hiting site visitor with "overloaded" sound

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: Just found the reason.
Seems like setVolume/getVolume range is now 0..1, not 0..100 as it was earlier
Documentation and playground just didn`t updated yet